# Read IP address from a config file Not Working

Tags: python, ftp

I'm a newbie at Python and trying to read IP and login info from a config file params.ini. The contents of the ini file are:

```
[Login]
FtpIP = 1.1.x.x
UID = anonymous
PWD = r@ee.com

[Directory]
Upload Directory = /
Home Directory = C:/Users/MyDocuments/Python/FilesUpload/**
```

The code that I have written is:

```
import ftplib
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.sections()

config.read('params.ini')

ftp = ftplib.FTP()
TargetIP = config.get('Login','FtpIP')
print (TargetIP)
ftp.connect(TargetIP)
```

I get this error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*
```

If I type the IP directly into the code, then it works. Please help.

Comment: Does the `print(TargetIP)` print the correct value?

Comment: yes it does. But when I try to make a connection, it fails.

Comment: Based on the error message, it appears as if the host is not responding. Are you sure nothing changed on the ftp host before you tried this?

Comment: So It's not a problem with reading data from config file, It's your problem with ftp connection. What's this `1.1.x.x` is it an example?

Comment: Compare the ip value retrieved from the file with the one you type in and see if there really the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
try:
   ftp = ftplib.FTP(config.get('Login','FtpIP'))
   ftp.login(config.get('Login','UID'), config.get('Login','PWD'))
except ftplib.all_errors, e:
   print str(e)
```